# I need to use all color without the need of defining each color specifically in the sass file

Tags: reactjs, sass, colors

the dev of the template I'm using defined a specific data-colors but I need to use all-colors so I'm asking if there's a way which I can give only the Hex code and it changes the background

scss file that defines colors :

```
$violet-color : rgb(127, 10, 236) !default ;
$info-color : rgb(0,0,200) !default ; 
..
```

scss file :

```
&[data-color="blue"] {
    @include sidebar-color($info-color);
  }
  &[data-color="green"] {
    @include sidebar-color($success-color);
  }
  &[data-color="orange"] {
    @include sidebar-color($orange-color);
  }
  &[data-color="red"] {
    @include sidebar-color($danger-color);
  }
  &[data-color="yellow"] {
    @include sidebar-color($warning-color);
  }
  &[data-color="violet"] {
    @include sidebar-color($violet-color) ; 
  }
  &[data-color="DA3"] {
    @include sidebar-color($DA3) ; 
  }
```

HTML file :

```
 <div className="sidebar"  data-color="blue" >
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to use a file for variables then don't, pass the values directly to `sidebar-color`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inline styles](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style):

```
<div className="sidebar" style={{ backgroundColor: '#00FF00' }} />
```

I'm not sure what else your `sidebar-color` mixin does, but you'd have to replicate that behaviour in your inline style.

Comment: No the inline styling isn't working for this issue I've tried but with no result the only change in the background is coming from the defined code in the sass file.

Comment: @PHANTOMXif then you'll need to post a runable example, there's no way to help you without seeing what's in `sidebar-color`

Comment: Yes It's quite difficuklt to showcase the issue because it's hard to demo, anyway thanks!